# why is the Controller class not providing the definition for IController interface's Execute method definition in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and while trying to learn controllers in MVC, I stumble into a page which got me confusing.
Controller class inherits from IController interface but i couldnot find any implementation of the

```
void Execute(RequestContext requestContext);
```

method in the controller but i could see ControllerBase which inherits the IController interface provide the implementation of the

```
void Execute(RequestContext requestContext);
```

Please explain.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Controller` isn't required to implement `IController.Execute` because its [base class](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L20), [`ControllerBase` already implements it](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerBase.cs#L125-L128).

```
    #region IController Members

    void IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        Execute(requestContext);
    }

    #endregion
```

The `Controller` class [*does not implement* `IController`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L20) directly, so it is not responsible for implementing its members. It does implement `IController` *indirectly* through `BaseController`, so `Controller` *is a* `IController` through [inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your reply,
but according to the c# concept any class which inherits the interface should provide its definition, right?
could you provide me any article which would help me to understand it better, Thank you

Comment: Yes, but `Controller` [does not implement `IController`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L20) directly. See my edit.

Comment: in system.web.mvc v5.0.0.0
it seems that the controller class implements icontroller directly, please correct me if i a wrong , Thanks in advance

public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase, IActionFilter, IAuthenticationFilter, IAuthorizationFilter, IDisposable, IExceptionFilter, IResultFilter, IAsyncController, IController, IAsyncManagerContainer

Comment: I already linked to the [latest version of MVC 5's `Controller`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L20) definition, and it clearly does not implement `IController`. Even if it did, the base class satisfies the contract already with its implementation, so there is no need to implement it again. Unfortunately, Microsoft seems to have a [cryptic tagging mechanism](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/releases), so I can't work out what tag goes with the 5.0.0.0 release to analyze the source at that point in time.